# Deployed Loki grafana,but not be able to run on a public url

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, grafana-loki

I have deployed Loki grafana stack with persistent 5GB storage in a gcp cloud. Then i have create ingress, and point loadbalancer IP to subdomain. when I hit the url,it will automatic redirect to https. Note that i haven't apply ssl so it will give me an error "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED".I have also changed url in "grafana,ini". I have deployed using https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/installation/helm/ . If anyone have face this issue please guide me.
I am using GKE, and deploy helm using the tutorial after that i use the following ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 8.3.5
    helm.sh/chart: grafana-6.21.3
  name: ingress-loki
  namespace: loki
spec:
  rules:
  - host: loki.*****.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: loki-grafana
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Comment: Your question lacks detail: "in a gcp cloud" is unhelpful, which service specifically? Presumably, because the tutorial references Helm and you say you created an Ingress, you're using Kubernetes Engine. Please add the commands that you ran and the results that you obtained in order that someone may be able to help you. It's a good idea to put yourself in the head of someone who's entirely unfamiliar with your setup but who wants to help you solve it. Anticipate the questions that they would have and try to answer them for them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.